# Will this work on a touchscreen?

Tags: touchscreen

I am trying to make a portable games console using the raspberry pi and i've came across a nintendo ds emulator. I'm trying to find a touchscreen for it but I can't find an accurate one. I found [this one](http://cpc.farnell.com/adafruit-industries/2315/rpi-pitft-hat-2-2-320x240/dp/SC13844?mckv=s_dc|pcrid|63733200017|kword||match||plid|&CMP=CPC-PLA) and I was wondering if i calibrated it with a stylus would it work like a ds?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that will work. You also might want to look at this article http://readwrite.com/2014/10/22/raspberry-pi-compatible-touchscreens

Comment: Would it be accurate enough?

Comment: When you plug in your touchscreen and power up the pi, it will automatically do a calibration test.

Comment: I've encountered a new problem. I am not sure if the [touchscreen I want to use](http://cpc.farnell.com/adafruit-industries/2315/rpi-pitft-hat-2-2-320x240/dp/SC13844?mckv=s_dc|pcrid|63733200017|kword||match||plid|&CMP=CPC-PLA) has the [pad at the bottom I need to solder wires to(Step 3).](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Portable-Games-Console/)

Comment: yes you will need to solder. Here look at this:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/assembly